# R.id.home gives wrong value?

Tags: java, android, android-actionbar, appcompatactivity

I'm using an `AppCompatActivity` with enabled `ShowHomeAsUpEnabled(true)`, but
when I click the Home button I get this

```
ID: 16908332
```

While `R.id.home` gives this

```
ID:2131492868
```

Does somebody know why that happens?

Comment: The home Button has ID `android.R.id.home`. The ID `R.id.home` is apparently defined in your resources somewhere, and won't be the same thing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should ask for `android.R.id.home`

Comment: android.R.id.* Predefined Android id. R.id your ids defined in your app. In this case you are using a predefined View so you should use their predefined id